# Implementation of multiple interfaces

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to know if is possible the multiple interface implementation in kotlin as java.

How can i do this...

```
interface MyInterface <T : Serializable, Iterable<T> { //.. }
```

...in Kotlin?

Comment: Hint: write the Java class, select the action "Convert Java file to Kotlin" in IntelliJ.

Comment: described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391246/8073652

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I did that but it generated a compilation error. That doesn't solve my question. Looks like doesn't work when working with generics.