# Is there any way for implementing multiple interfaces in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In **java** we implement *multiple interfaces* separated by comma, but in **kotlin** nothing as such was found.
So, can we do it in case of kotlin, or we need to add in particular at every places?

Edit:
class A : A,B was in some of the answers below.
So the **extends** and **implements** are done with same syntax in kotlin

Comment: The [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html) would seem to indicate that you can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: Works for me: `interface A {fun a()} interface B {fun b()} class C : A, B {override fun a() {}override fun b() {}}`. Please specify what you've tried, and where you're getting errors

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391217/extend-and-implement-at-the-same-time-in-kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend and implement at the same time in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391217/extend-and-implement-at-the-same-time-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can implement multiple interface in kotlin like this below -

```
interface A {
    fun callMe() {
        println("From interface A")
    }
}
interface B  {
    fun callMeToo() {
        println("From interface B")
    }
}
// implements two interfaces A and B
class Child: A, B
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val obj = Child()
    obj.callMe()
    obj.callMeToo()
}
```

Comment: So the **extends** and **implements** are done with same syntax in kotlin

Comment: yeh after : you can extend class and implement interface seperated by comma, but Multiple class inheritance is prohibited while multiple interfaces may be implemented by a single class.

Comment: @PravinYadav if it helps you please mark answer as accepted thats will help others too. thanks

Comment: Is it possible to extend multiple class in kotlin?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh No its not possible.